# Left/right sliding menu

Tags: jquery, menu, sliding

I have this menu that's basically an horizontal items sliding bar. All menu items have specific default css properties. I want the items to change their size and left/right margins when they reach the center of the main container and reset to the default values when they leave it (or are outside of it). See my schematic.

[image]

There's a left/right button that will trigger which direction it will slide.
I know there are libraries for this sort of thing, but I really want the simplest possible thing.
Here's the HTML markup:

```
<div id="leftBtn">Left</div>
<div id="rightBtn">Right</div>

<div id="centerArea">
    <div id="menuContainer">
        <div id="menuItem_1" class="menuItem"></div>
        <div id="menuItem_2" class="menuItem"></div>
        <div id="menuItem_3" class="menuItem"></div>
        <div id="menuItem_4" class="menuItem"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Vngt/).

Thank you.

Pedro

Comment: menuItem_position = - (menuItem_place * 200) + 25; http://jsfiddle.net/2Vngt/1/

Comment: That fixes the centering issue. Thanx David! You don't happen to know how to set different css values for the inside/outside center area, do you?

Comment: the best thing would be to add a css class to the active element: http://jsfiddle.net/2Vngt/3/

Comment: Works great. There's just one problem: it won't run in IE8. Could you make use of the jQuery animate() instead of using css3? Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GEfLP/)

It follows following approach
* enclose contents of `.menuItem` in another container, `.container` so that it can move freely inside it's parent.
* use the `menuItem_place` to get particular `.menuItem` that's in center.

Comment: Works great too! By the way, is it possible to have a mouseover+click option as well?

Comment: yes certainly, using CSS `:hover` or `jQuery.hover(..,..)` .. 
Edit: ah, do you mean `click menuItem to scroll next`?

Comment: Not the buttons. :) I meant the items themselves - when clicked bring them to the middle.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Thank you Ejay!

Comment: Ejay, there's just two things left to do: **disable left/right buttons** when the items reach their limits (I tried to play with the some if statements, but I didn't get it) and **add a simple mouseenter/mouseleave (scale resize)** that disables itself also when reaching the left/right end boundaries. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkUYm/) update.