# Navbar menu slide with two button left and right

Tags: jquery, css, menu, slide

Hi am working on a new CMS with bootstrap 3 and I want to have 2 buttons "<<" and ">>" on each side of the menu and when clicked it slides the menu !!!

excuse my bad english!!
Here is my code :

```
<div class=" navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">

        <a href="index.php"><img src="assets/img/logo2.png" class="navbar-brand"><small class="navbar-brand"> Compagnie Tunisienne De Meubles</small></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon-home-2"></span>Acceuil</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                 <li ><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon-industrial-building"></span>Société</a></li>             
                     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li class="dropdown" >
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

                  <span class="glyphicon-glass-1"></span> Nos Produits <b class="caret"></b>
                     </a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus">
                        <li><a href="#" >Coffres Forts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Mobiliers Métalliques</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Rayonnages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Mobiliers Hospitaliers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Portes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Des produits de la poste</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >La sous traitance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Divers</a></li>

                        </ul>
                </li>               
                <li class="dropdown" >
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

                   <span class="glyphicon-globe-6"></span> Nos Références <b class="caret"></b>
                     </a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" >Références en Tunisie</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Références à l'étranger</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li> 
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon-newspaper-1"></span>News</a></li>  
                <li ><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon-location-6"></span>Contact</a></li>                
                </ul>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: At risk of repeating the most over-used comment on this site, What have you tried?

Comment: I didn't try anything i searched the web and i found nothing :/

Comment: what have you done already? post it.

Comment: So I recommend that you give it a go and do your best at researching it. Here at Stack overflow, we don't help you get started. We give you a hand when you're stuck implementing the solution.

Comment: thank you for replying anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

[Left/right sliding menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924346/left-right-sliding-menu?rq=1)

Accepted answer includes demo (full code at jsfiddle) see it.. 
You can position the things as per your need..

If you don't know css.. Do not ask here just go and learn css http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp and after learning positioning if you try to implement and got stuck at particular implementation/technique you will be welcome here better